# Should IOBufferMemoryDescriptor be released of free'd?

Tags: driverkit, macos-system-extension

I am looking at the documentation of [`IOBufferMemoryDescriptor`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/driverkit/iobuffermemorydescriptor). It says *"... Except where noted, you are also responsible for releasing buffers that you allocate."*.

[`IOBufferMemoryDescriptor::free`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/kernel/iobuffermemorydescriptor/3180456-free) also exists. My questions is: should I use `free` or `release` (or maybe both) to do the cleanup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`free()` is called automatically when the last handle is dropped using `OSSafeReleaseNULL`. (This calls `release()` internally, but it's usually best to use the macro.)

So, never call the `free()` method directly, you only need to care about it in the context of overriding it in your own subclasses. Always use the reference counting mechanism on `OSObject`-derived classes.